# Download form HTML on submit (React)

Tags: reactjs, forms, download

```
I have a form (example snippet below) that simply outputs state on submit.

This is as expected but now I want to save the rendered output to a file (.html) - How can I achieve this? I am assuming it would involve node but not sure since I am pretty new to React.

Edit: The question has mostly been answered, I am updating the code snippet to highlight a new issue that I am having. - I am trying to output a full HTML string using the renderToStaticMarkup method, however, the method is converting characters (',<,>,&) to (&quot; &lt; &gt &amp;) on output.
```

Ideally, I would like the rendered file to be an actual working HTML file that you can open in a browser. As it stands, the current output is not functioning due to the character conversion issue.

I have a feeling that there may be a way to escape the character encoding in some way, however, since I am new to react I'm not fully sure of a working solution.

```
Thank you in advance for any help on this.

        

    
function Result(props) {
    const { image, title, bodyText, btnText, btnUrl, btnColor } = props;

    return <>{`<!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <head>
      <title> ${title} </title>
      <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <!--<![endif]-->
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style type="text/css">
    
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
          -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
    
        table,
        td {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
          mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }
    
      </style>
      <!--[if !mso]><!-->
      <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
          .mj-column-per-100 {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100%;
          }
          .mj-column-px-600 {
            width: 600px !important;
            max-width: 600px;
          }
        }
      </style>
      <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
          .small p {
            font-size: 9px !important;
          }
        }

      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div style="">
        <table class="body" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="text-align:center; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
              <font style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:5px 0 5px 0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
            <tr>
          
                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="width:200px;"> <img alt="Company Name" height="auto" src="" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;"
                                    width="200"> </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>
              
            </tr>
          
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          
          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
            <tr>
          
                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="width:600px;"> <img alt="" height="auto" src="http://image.e.campingworldrv.com/lib/fe9915737d640c7f75/m/1/648eb085-3d86-4be1-a8e7-f3d8f8023c53.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;"
                                            width="600"> </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>
              
            </tr>
          
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          
          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
            <tr>
          
                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:580px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                          <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#000000;"> <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size:24px">${age} ${bodyText}</span><br><br><span style="font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">${bodyText}</span> </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" vertical-align="middle" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:separate;line-height:100%;">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" role="presentation" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;background:#000000;" valign="middle"> <a href="#" style="background:#000000;color:#ffffff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:120%;Margin:0;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;" target="_blank">
                  ${btnText}
                </a> </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>
              
            </tr>
          
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          
          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
            <tr>
          
                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <p style="border-top:solid 1px #6a6a6a;font-size:1;margin:0px auto;width:100%;"> </p>
                                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
            <table
               align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-top:solid 1px #6a6a6a;font-size:1;margin:0px auto;width:600px;" role="presentation" width="600px"
            >
              <tr>
                <td style="height:0;line-height:0;">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>
              
            </tr>
          
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        
          
          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 10px 20px 10px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
            <tr>
          
                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:580px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;font-size:10px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#6a6a6a;"> Don't want anymore emails from us? <a href="http://www.unsubscribe.com/">Unsubscribe</a>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>
              
            </tr>
          
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <![endif]-->
      </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>`}</>;
}

function download(filename, text) {
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute(
        'href',
        'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text)
    );
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function BasicHtml(props) {
    const { title, children } = props;

    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>{title}</title>
            </head>
            <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}

export default class FormComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { name: '', age: null, submitted: false };

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        this.generateHtmlFile();
    };

    generateHtmlFile = () => {
        const { name, age } = this.state;
        const formHtml = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            <BasicHtml title={name}>
                <FormComponent />
            </BasicHtml>
        );
        const resultHtml = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            <BasicHtml title={name}>
                <Result name={name} age={age} />
            </BasicHtml>
        );
        download('result.html', resultHtml);
        download('form.html', formHtml);
    };

    render() {
        const { name, age, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Name:{' '}
                        <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Age:{' '}
                        <input
                            name="age"
                            type="number"
                            value={this.state.age}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <br />
                {submitted ? <Result name={name} age={age} /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
        
        ReactDOM.render(<FormComponent />, document.body);
    
    
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code, I found a solution. Hope that works out :)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server';

function Result(props) {
  const { image, title, bodyText, btnText, btnUrl, btnColor, age, name } = props;

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
      <title> ${name} </title>
      <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <!--<![endif]-->
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style type="text/css">

        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
          -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        table,
        td {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
          mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }

      </style>
      <!--[if !mso]><!-->
      <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
          .mj-column-per-100 {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100%;
          }
          .mj-column-px-600 {
            width: 600px !important;
            max-width: 600px;
          }
        }
      </style>
      <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
          .small p {
            font-size: 9px !important;
          }
        }

      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div style="">
        <table class="body" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" style="text-align:center; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
              <font style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:5px 0 5px 0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>

                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="width:200px;"> <img alt="Company Name" height="auto" src="" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;"
                                    width="200"> </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>

            </tr>

                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>

                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="width:600px;"> <img alt="" height="auto" src="http://image.e.campingworldrv.com/lib/fe9915737d640c7f75/m/1/648eb085-3d86-4be1-a8e7-f3d8f8023c53.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;"
                                            width="600"> </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>

            </tr>

                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>

                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:580px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                          <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#000000;"> <span style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size:24px">${age} ${bodyText}</span><br><br><span style="font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">${bodyText}</span> </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" vertical-align="middle" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:separate;line-height:100%;">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" role="presentation" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;cursor:auto;padding:10px 25px;background:#000000;" valign="middle"> <a href="#" style="background:#000000;color:#ffffff;font-family:Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:120%;Margin:0;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;" target="_blank">
                  ${btnText}
                </a> </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>

            </tr>

                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>

                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <p style="border-top:solid 1px #6a6a6a;font-size:1;margin:0px auto;width:100%;"> </p>
                                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
            <table
               align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-top:solid 1px #6a6a6a;font-size:1;margin:0px auto;width:600px;" role="presentation" width="600px"
            >
              <tr>
                <td style="height:0;line-height:0;">
                  &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>

            </tr>

                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>


          <table
             align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" style="width:600px;" width="600"
          >
            <tr>
              <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
          <![endif]-->
        <div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 10px 20px 10px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;">
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <tr>

                <td
                   class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:580px;"
                >
              <![endif]-->
                  <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;font-size:10px;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#6a6a6a;"> Don't want anymore emails from us? <a href="http://www.unsubscribe.com/">Unsubscribe</a>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                </td>

            </tr>

                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <![endif]-->
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
  `
  }} />;
}

function download(filename, text) {
  let element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute(
    'href',
    'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text)
  );
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function BasicHtml(props) {
  const { title, children } = props;

  return (
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { name: this.props.name, age: this.props.age, submitted: false };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    this.generateHtmlFile();
  };

  generateHtmlFile = () => {
    const { name, age } = this.state;
    const formHtml = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
      <BasicHtml title={name}>
        <FormComponent name={name} age={age} />
      </BasicHtml>
    );
    const resultHtml = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
      <Result name={name} age={age} />
    );
    download('result.html', resultHtml);
    download('form.html', formHtml);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, age, submitted } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{age}</div>
        <div>{name}</div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:{' '}
            <input
              name="name"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <br />
          <label>
            Age:{' '}
            <input
              name="age"
              type="number"
              value={this.state.age}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <br />
        {submitted ? <Result name={name} age={age} /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can use download function for every kind of files, and also pass every component to `ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup` method and convert it to pain text and finally pass to download method, or if you want to render a text/plain HTML, you have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: Thank you for the response. - Is there any way to show a live example of this? 

Possibly a code snippet, or an example that uses my form code above?

Comment: Hamed, thank you very much. - This solution did the trick and I was able to download my string as an HTML file on submit. Now I have a new problem, the code provided above was just for example purposes. I am trying to output actual HTML in the downloaded file and it is replacing characters with unwanted results. Would you know a way to escape this behavior?

Comment: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">` becomes &lt;html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot; xmlns:v=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml&quot; xmlns:o=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office&quot;&gt;

Comment: Your welcome @Dr.Tenma. What do you mean with 'output actual HTML in the downloaded file'? I didn't understand.

Comment: Sorry, meaning the Result function contains a string with HTML code. Something like this `function Result(props) { const { name, age } = props; return {`<html><head></head><body>Your name is ${name} and you are ${age} years old.</body></html>`}; } `

Comment: You want to remove main HTML tags or what?

Comment: I am needing the result to a output large HTML file which would be downloaded on submit. -. The renderToStaticMarkup function is currently converting (',<,>,&) to (&quot; &lt; &gt &amp;) - is there any way to escape this functionality?

Comment: Please add the example string for this situation

Comment: The code sample above has been updated, I've also added additional context to my question.

Comment: I copy-paste the example and run it. But the values did not change to HTML entities. Are you sure about this?

Comment: my apologies. - I forgot to update the snippet with the added functionality you provided. The snippet is now updated. When you have a moment please try again and see the results. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208698/discussion-between-hamed-navabian-and-dr-tenma).